# Android RatingBar shows less stars

Tags: android

I am trying to show a rating bar in a `ListView`.
No matter what I tried:

```
    viewHolder.viewOnlyQuickRatingBar.setNumStars(5);
```

or:

```
android:numStars="5"
```

or both of the above I always get the same result.
In Android 5.0 I get a 5-star rating bar and in Android 4.1.2 I get 4-star rating bar.

The weird is when I try to show the rating bar (using the, above, xml code only) in `Activity` and not in a `ListView` everything is working just fine.

How can I get a 5-star rating bar under any circumstances?

Comment: Did you try setMax before setNumStars?

Comment: In your xml, try to set style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" if your view has not enough place to draw 5 stars

Comment: @Zharf: Yes, I tried this also but nothing changes!

Comment: @Gordak: Please answer the question to vote your answer as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From experience, adding :

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

in your xml can help if your view has not enough place to draw 5 stars.

Comment: I noticed that when I apply this style the stars always (all of them) selected. I don't want them to be selected, all of them, but some of them!

Comment: I can't help you for now. I'll check the code of one of my project when I have time to see if there is another trick to apply.

Comment: Ok. Whenever you could, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I created a custom RatingBar using my star icons and everything works like a charm!